# High gloss finish for wooden sign

Tags: finishing

I am currently making a wooden sign with lots of details in it for interior use. I usually finish those with a coat of danish oil, but for a change, I wanted to apply a high gloss finish. My main concern is the amount of details in the sign which would be hard to apply a finish uniformly to them, plus reaching the depth of the v-carved details.

Is there a finish which is easy to apply and forgiving which would achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Many high gloss finishes such as varnish, lacquer and shellac can be sprayed (either from a can or a HVLP) which makes applying it to irregular surfaces a bit easier compared to brushing. That said there is no reason you couldn't achieve the results you are looking for with a brush and some patience.

Thinning the finishes will also make it easier to get the finish to flow into the detailed areas but will require more coats.

Comment: The magazine's claim that the clip-on handles for spray cans really do make them behave much more like a "real" spray system and produce better results -- good enough that for small projects spray cans may be a perfectly reasonable choice. Color me skeptical but hopeful..